# Rotate and transform connected rigid bodies in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move connected rigid bodies as in image example, one of them needs to rotate around a point. Then using ground check I want to rotate it back to line
I tried using hinge joint 2d, using angle limits, but can not control rotating angle.

How can I achieve this effect? thanks.

[image: rotate position]]

Edit:
Tagged both rigidbodies as fixed angle and then applied rotation to upper object

```
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){

        zRotation += 45;

        myGameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(myGameObject.transform.rotation.x, myGameObject.transform.rotation.y, zRotation);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I achieve this effect?

Point to the object then rotate it.

First you want to find the GameObject.

```
GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Object Name");
```

Save the original rotation so you can return to it.

```
Quaternion originalPos = g.transform.rotation;
```

Then rotate it to your liking.

```
g.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(x,y,z,w);
```

In addition you could use iTween to smoothen out the rotation.

Comment: Thank you I was really thinking and overcomplex solutions... This actually works and what I want to achieve. Just additionaly I tagged both objects as fixed angle in editor... Than I achieved the effect..